# Wpf show image dynamic URI

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a custom user control that has to show an image 'dynamically' based on the value of a property my user control is bound to.

Example

```
   <Image Source="Resources/{0}.png" />
```

Source property of the image is incomplete: the missing value {0} should be somehow replaced with my model's value to retrieve the image.

How can i achieve this in wpf?
Thank you

Comment: Use a binding converter, which would convert your property to an ImageSource via a WPF Pack Uri.

Comment: @Clemens Could you please provide a link or a code snippet? I'm very new to wpf, an example is important to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved using a value converter:

```
 public class ImageSelector : IValueConverter
 {
     public object Convert( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
     {
         if( value == null )
             return null;

         string basePath = System.IO.Path.Combine( Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"Resources\Devices" );
         string imageName = String.Format( "{0}.png", value.ToString() );
         string imageLocation = System.IO.Path.Combine( basePath, imageName );

         if( !File.Exists( imageLocation ) )
            imageLocation = System.IO.Path.Combine( basePath, "ImageUnavailable.png" );

         return new BitmapImage( new Uri( imageLocation ) );
     }

     public object ConvertBack( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
     {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
     }
}
```

XAML:

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:ImageSelector x:Key="imageSelector"/>
 </UserControl.Resources>

 ...

 <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource imageSelector}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your can solve this by adding another property to your view model.

View model code:

```
    private string _yourProperty;

    public string YourProperty
    {
        get { return _yourProperty; }
        set
        {
            if (_yourProperty == value) return;
            _yourProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("YourProperty");
            OnPropertyChanged("YourImageSource");
        }
    }

    //this code is just for demo.
    public BitmapImage YourImageSource
    {
        get
        {
            return new BitmapImage(BuildUriFromYourProperty());
        }
    }
```

Xaml code:

```
<Image Source="{Binding YourImageSource}"/>
```

Comment: In order to serve as a binding source, a property doesn't have to be a dependency property. And your post does not answer the question, which was how to create the ImageSource (or an appropriate URI) from another view model property.

Comment: @Clemens thank you for comment, i misunderstood the question.